# Expo Web bundling bug: Multiple files match the route name

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

I am making a simple React-native expo application. The application was started using the create-expo-app to initialize it. Everything was working well for awhile but there is a bug that came up where the application fails to bundle correctly for web and fails with an Uncaught Error only in Web Developer Mode. Note, both ISO, Andriod and Expo Go app on the phone all work perfectly fine and error only occurs for Web.

Testing what is going on, I have narrowed it down to the first file in the first folder in the app directory is whats get the duplication problem. If I change the folder or filename it changes to always be the first folder and file, so isn't dependent on the content of the file. In the example below, I added a folder (aa) and a test file to reproduce the error. I am unfamiliar with the bundling process for the web and how to approach fixing this issue, direction in where to start would be appreciated.

So far I have tried clearing the expo cache with "expo start -c" and "yarn cache clear" then deleting the .expo folder entirely to ensure that the .expo/web/cache was entirely rebuilt but still getting same error. Occurrence of bug cannot be traced to previous git instance either. This error still occurs in older previous working versions of the application.

[image]

Here is my package.json if that helps:

```
    {
  "name": "beta-boost",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "expo": "~48.0.10",
    "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-router": "^1.5.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "firebase": "^9.19.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.10",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "thunk": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
    "eslint": "^8.37.0",
    "eslint-config-universe": "^11.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~48.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "universe/native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any direction of where to start fixing this issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read and help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, I was using `npx expo-cli start --tunnel` to test on my iOS device. This lead to a similar problem with my _layout.js file which appeared first in my file structure (excluding the .expo folder).

Using `expo start`, `npx expo-cli start` all lead to similar issues.

I can't offer much guidance on *why* the error is happening but, using node package manager to start my app, `npm start`, allowed me to view my changes on web while not being able to view them on mobile and switching back to NPX and expo to start allowed me to view on mobile.

Quite a temporary fix but it allows me to test on all platforms, if anybody can provide further explanation or a permanent fix, by all means comment.

Comment: Hi, I never quite figured out the issue, I loaded it open into xCode and was able to have a better debugging experience. I found that I was missing a dependency for firebase, I am very unsure how that caused this effect but adding the dependency "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2". Fixed the issue for me. Happy coding!

Comment: Hey @ColinHale I am having the same issue, but for me adding @react-native-async-storage/async-storage did not fix it. I appreciate you adding a comment explaining something that you did that fixed it for you, though.